# Need help to join data to single row in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am running this query and result includes 3 different rows. I need to combine them to form a single row. I am able to filter out of joins till here only but am stuck after having these repeating rows at the end.

Also tried group by at the end with all columns but its not affecting the result.

I need username, Notes and endpointIP in single row.

```
select DISTINCT s.id,
s.name,
(CASE when sf.FieldName='username' then si.ItemValue
END) AS Username,

(CASE when sf.FieldName='notes' then si.ItemValue
END) AS Notes,

f.FolderName,
PARSENAME(replace(st.typename,'-','.'),3) as AuthenticationType,
PARSENAME(replace(st.typename,'-','.'),2) as Platform,
PARSENAME(replace(st.typename,'-','.'),4) as EndpointScope,

(CASE when sf.FieldName='password' then si.ItemValue
END) AS Password,

(CASE when sf.FieldName='search-name' 
    then SUBSTRING(si.ItemValue,0,CHARINDEX('_',si.ItemValue))
END) AS EndpointIP
from tbsec s 
left join tbFolder f on f.folderid = s.FolderId
left join tbtype st on s.TypeID = st.TypeID
left join tbField sf on sf.TypeID = st.TypeID
left join tbItem si on si.FieldID = sf.FieldID
where s.Name='Testing-DS'
and (CASE when sf.FieldName='password' then si.ItemValue
END) is null
and (CASE when sf.FieldName='notes' 
or sf.FieldName='username' 
or sf.FieldName='search-name' then si.ItemValue
END) is not null
```

Here is the output:

I need to get all the data in single row as I am putting conditions to filter null and not null values to be required.

[image: Output]

```
         id         name            Username        Notes       FolderName           AuthenticationType  Platform     EndpointScope     Password    EndpointIP
        410     Testing-DS          NULL            NULL     Customer1_Dev            KBA               Unix           Manual          NULL         9.156.20.184
        410     Testing-DS          newtestIDKBA    NULL     Customer1_Dev            KBA               Unix           Manual          NULL             NULL
        410     Testingt-DS         NULL           For test  Customer1_Dev            KBA               Unix           Manual          NULL             NULL
```

Comment: Please show sample data and expected results (as formatted text).

Comment: As i am not able to format here, can you pls copy the image link from here and look at the expected result.

Comment: You certainly can format here... google formatting data on stackoverflow. Hint, formatting as code will correct it. Also I had your image displayed, but you undid my edits.

Comment: Now that I fixed the image, you can see it's pretty much unreadable. There is a markdown/commonmark format for tabular data you should use.

Comment: Also, it's not clear what data you want in that single row.

Comment: I have edited it again. Yea i need username, Notes and endpointIP in single row.

Comment: Your 2 images are identical? Please use formatted text instead of images as already said.

Comment: Done with editing and formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes SQl-Server versions differ for Frontend and Backend. Thus, "With" clause might not be supported in those versions. Try using Derived tables/Subqueries

Well you can try this:

```
select id, max(Notes) as Notes, max(userName) as userName, .......,max(endpointip) as EndpointIp
from

(select DISTINCT s.id,
s.name,
(CASE when sf.FieldName='username' then si.ItemValue
END) AS Username,

(CASE when sf.FieldName='notes' then si.ItemValue
END) AS Notes,

f.FolderName,
PARSENAME(replace(st.typename,'-','.'),3) as AuthenticationType,
PARSENAME(replace(st.typename,'-','.'),2) as Platform,
PARSENAME(replace(st.typename,'-','.'),4) as EndpointScope,

(CASE when sf.FieldName='password' then si.ItemValue
END) AS Password,

(CASE when sf.FieldName='search-name' 
    then SUBSTRING(si.ItemValue,0,CHARINDEX('_',si.ItemValue))
END) AS EndpointIP
from tbsec s 
left join tbFolder f on f.folderid = s.FolderId
left join tbtype st on s.TypeID = st.TypeID
left join tbField sf on sf.TypeID = st.TypeID
left join tbItem si on si.FieldID = sf.FieldID
where s.Name='Testing-DS'
and (CASE when sf.FieldName='password' then si.ItemValue
END) is null
and (CASE when sf.FieldName='notes' 
or sf.FieldName='username' 
or sf.FieldName='search-name' then si.ItemValue
END) is not null) derivedtable
group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have, it seems you want to merge all 3 rows in your data into one. If so, the simplest thing to do of course is:

```
with detail as
(
select DISTINCT s.id,
s.name,
(CASE when sf.FieldName='username' then si.ItemValue
END) AS Username,

(CASE when sf.FieldName='notes' then si.ItemValue
END) AS Notes,

f.FolderName,
PARSENAME(replace(st.typename,'-','.'),3) as AuthenticationType,
PARSENAME(replace(st.typename,'-','.'),2) as Platform,
PARSENAME(replace(st.typename,'-','.'),4) as EndpointScope,

(CASE when sf.FieldName='password' then si.ItemValue
END) AS Password,

(CASE when sf.FieldName='search-name' 
    then SUBSTRING(si.ItemValue,0,CHARINDEX('_',si.ItemValue))
END) AS EndpointIP
from tbsec s 
left join tbFolder f on f.folderid = s.FolderId
left join tbtype st on s.TypeID = st.TypeID
left join tbField sf on sf.TypeID = st.TypeID
left join tbItem si on si.FieldID = sf.FieldID
where s.Name='Testing-DS'
and (CASE when sf.FieldName='password' then si.ItemValue
END) is null
and (CASE when sf.FieldName='notes' 
or sf.FieldName='username' 
or sf.FieldName='search-name' then si.ItemValue
END) is not null
)
select id, max(Notes) as Notes, max(userName) as userName, .......,max(endpointip) as EndpointIp
from detail
group by id
```

You may need to explain in more detail about the individual tables to get a better solution.

Comment: This will work in case if i put where condition "where s.Name='Testing-DS'", i guess without this condition Group by using MAX function on strings will not give desired results.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant by better explanation. If you want to merge all those rows into one, you need to determine which column best represents that row AKA a unique key. For example, if you say that the name is the most important, we group by the name instead of ID which means you end up with 2 rows. This is why you are asked for expected output so we see exactly what you expect to see from the given input. So from the data you have provided, what is the expected output?

Comment: Well as it is applying on id level, so MAX is not impacting anything here. It is working fine. fine.

Comment: Also, this query works good in SQL server but i have a tool consisting of kinda SQL interpreter which generate results based on query. It is not working out there and i don't have write access to that one. Is there any alternate way to write this query without clause "with as" ?

Comment: Yes, happens the same with me in fron-end tool.

Comment: So what you usually do? Do you have any alternatives?

Comment: I wrote answer. kindly check!

Comment: Hi @Sunny, just for future reference, what is the front end tool that doesn't accept "with" statements?

Comment: Its an internal retail tool.